# Get a sum of all values that have matching keys in a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a function that will sum the values based on the key. Here is a sample object:

```
{
  "US": {
    "q": 1,
    "Atlanta": {
      "q": 2
    },
    "Boston": {
      "q": 1
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to call a function like:

```
var sum = plucky("q", obj);
// sum === 4;
```

The function I'm using, which I believe I found from an SO post somewhere in the past *almost* does the right thing:

```
function pluckDeepKey(key, obj) {
  if (_.has(obj, key)) {
    return obj[key];
  }
  return _.reduce(_.flatten(_.map(obj, function(v) {
    return _.isObject(v) ? pluckDeepKey(key, v) : [];
  }), false), function(a,b) { return a + b });
}
```

However, due to: `return obj[key]` it finds the first `"q"`, returns that value, and quits. I've been scratching my head all day, and thought it might be helpful to others if I throw the question out to SO.

### Edit

I thought it might be useful to SO and my future self to collect the different approaches I've explored into the body of the question.

#### Vanilla JavaScript (from dfsq)

```
function plucky(key, obj) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, prop) && key === prop) {
            sum += obj[prop];
        }
        else if (_.isObject(obj[prop])) {
            sum += plucky(key, obj[prop]);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

#### Lodash (Underscore?) Functional Example (via Bergi)

```
function pluckDeepKey(key, obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, function(a, v) {
    return a + (_.isObject(v) ? pluckDeepKey(key, v) : 0);
  }, _.has(obj, key) ? obj[key] : 0);
}
```

#### Mori.js & Immutable.js Functional Example

```
function moriDeepKey(key, mmap) {
  return m.reduce_kv(
    function(a, k, v) { return a + (m.is_map(v) ? moriDeepKey(key, v) : 0); },
    m.has_key(mmap, key) ? mmap.get(key) : 0,
    mmap
  );
}
function iDeepKey(key, imap) {
  return imap.reduce(
    function(a, v, k) { return a + (v instanceof I.Map ? iDeepKey(key, v) : 0); },
    imap.has(key) ? imap.get(key) : 0,
    imap
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think plain javascript function would look more comprehensive and simpler:

```
function plucky(key, obj) {

    var sum = 0;

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && key === prop) {
            sum += obj[prop];
        }
        else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
            sum += plucky(key, obj[prop]);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

```js
function plucky(key, obj) {

    var sum = 0;

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && key === prop) {
            sum += obj[prop];
        } 
        else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
            sum += plucky(key, obj[prop]);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}


var obj = {
    "US": {
        "q": 1,
        "Atlanta": {"q": 2},
        "Boston": {"q": 1}
    }
};
var sum = plucky("q", obj);
alert(sum);
```

Comment: @dfsg Brilliant! I was getting close to this, but thought that the `var sum = 0` would wipe out the sum on every recurse. Is it shadowing the previous level's sum?

Comment: @scott_trinh: `var sum` is local to every call of `plucky()`.

Comment: @scott_trinh Sort of. Inside of every `plucky` call its own isolated scope, so `sum` from the other level does not effect nested one.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

> However, due to: `return obj[key]` it finds the first `"q"`, returns that value, and quits.

Just sum the two parts (`obj.q` and the recursive calls) instead, by using the value as the start of the accumulator:

```
function pluckDeepKey(key, obj) {
  return _.reduce(_.map(obj, function(v) {
    return _.isObject(v) ? pluckDeepKey(key, v) : 0;
  }), function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
  }, _.has(obj, key) ? obj[key] : 0);
}
```

I also have removed the unncessary `flatten` call (`pluckDeepKey` always returns a number, the empty arrray should just be `0`). If you want, you can also join the `reduce` with the `map` to

```
function pluckDeepKey(key, obj) {
  return _.reduce(obj, function(a, v) {
    return a + (_.isObject(v) ? pluckDeepKey(key, v) : 0);
  }, _.has(obj, key) ? obj[key] : 0);
}
```

Comment: This is how I actually implemented this, but I gave the answer to dfsq since I got his (correct) answer first, but I like how this reads without the explict `sum` variable. Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you can do this more functionally with everything built-in,  and using recursion as well:

```
var plucky = function(key, obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, k) {
    if ({}.toString.call(obj[k]) == '[object Object]') {
      return acc + plucky(key, obj[k])
    }
    if (k === key) {
      return acc + obj[k]
    }
    return acc
  },0)
}
```

Comment: Nice! However I think you should check for object better, because `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: Yeah, I was leaving a comment, but I might as well just change it. Done.

Comment: This would also include values from non-`q`-named properties, which I think is not asked for.

Comment: @Bergi: You are right. This doesn't work like OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
function plucky(key, obj) {
    var sum = 0;
    if(typeof obj == "object") {
        for(var val in obj) {
            if(typeof obj[val] == "object") {
                sum += plucky(key, obj[val]);
            } else if(val == key) {
                sum += obj[val];
            }
        }
    } else if(val == key) {
        sum += obj[val];
    }
    return sum;
}
```